# How to calculate date of tuesday of current week?

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

In power automate (desktop), regardless if it is monday or saturday, how can I calculate the tuesday of the current week?

Answer (score 0):

Try this algorithm:

1. Get current datetime in %CurrentDateTime%
2. Format %CurrentDateTime% to get the Day of Week with "dddd" format, or use the built in property %CurrentDateTime.DayOfWeek%
3. Get the number of days to add to %CurrentDateTime% given Day of Week by the following logic:

- a) For sunday, 4
- b) For monday, 3
- c) For tuesday, 2
- d) For wednesday, 1
- e) For thursday, 0
- f) For friday, -1
- g) For saturday, -2

4. Add that number of days to %CurrentDateTime%